# When working with Java libraries in Kotlin, is it more idiomatic to use ? or !! on method return values?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and there's a common pattern that I'm not sure how to deal with most correctly. Take this code, for example, which doesn't compile:

```
git_repo?.add().addFilepattern()
```

`add()` is a call in the JGit library which is purely Java, so its return type is `AddCommand!`.

I have two options:

```
git_repo?.add()!!.addFilepattern("test.txt")
```

and

```
git_repo?.add()?.addFilepattern("test.txt")
```

Both work fine and given that

1. I don't know the intricacies of the library implementation,
2. the documentation of the JGit library doesn't specify whether `add()` can return null, and
3. within this context I'd typically expect `add()` to not return a null

Which version is more idiomatically correct to write in Kotlin? It seems that this would be a fairly common issue to deal with since basically every non-Kotlin library would introduce this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `?.` [safe operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) and then put your own exception at the end after an `?:` [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).  This way you get a message that is meaningful.  Using just `!!` isn't a very helpful message to someone down the road who has no idea what the intricacies were either.

```
val cmd = gitRepo.add()?.addFilepattern("test.txt") ?: throw IllegalStateException("assert: gitRepo.add() returned an unexpected null")
cmd.doSomething() // never is null guaranteed
```

If the value is every `null` you will have a custom error.

> assert: gitRepo.add() returned an unexpected null

And after this line, you will not have to `null` check because the result of the expression is guaranteed never to be `null`.

If you inspect the code of the other library and ensure it would never ever be `null` no matter what, then a `!!` is appropriate.  But if not sure, do one better with the custom message.

Note I dropped the first `?.` from your example because I'm assuming `git_repo` itself is not nullable.  Plus I renamed it not to have an underscore which isn't normal Kotlin naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `git_repo` will always return a value`!!` is fine in that case.

It is ugly but `!!` will always be there when you use Java libraries, and you can't avoid it.

The only reason i would use `git_repo?.add()?.addFilepattern("test.txt")`, would be if you are returning a value, and you want the value to be nullable so that your calling method can handle the nullable.

```
fun nullableMethod(): string? {
  return git_repo?.add()?.addFilepattern("test.txt")
}

fun callingMethod() {
   if(this.nullableMethod() != null) {

   }
   //Else
}
```

If you are guaranteed it is never going to `null`, use `!!`